# How to get the content from my database in views.py? [Django]

Tags: python, django

I am trying to print the `content` fields from my database,
Here's my `models.py` file:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    read_time = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    view_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Here's my `views.py` file:-

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    def get_object(self):
        obj = super().get_object()
        obj.view_count += 1
        obj.save()
        return obj
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        all_texts = {
            'texts': context.content
        }
        print(all_texts[texts])
        return context
```

I am trying to access all the data's from the `content` field from my database,
But the above way is not working, Is there any way I can access all the data's from the `content` field, because I have to perform some action on these fields, like calculate the `read_time` of any content, based on the length of it.

Comment: Just query all objects (table entries) of `Post` and loop over the content fields for each object in Queryset to manipulate them

Comment: Can you elaborate with `code`, I am new to Django. It would be of great help. @Jonas

Comment: Sure bro, see answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do *not* have to override the [**`.get_queryset(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_context_data) for that, since the object is already passed to the context. You can simply render it in the template with:

```
{{ object.content }}
```

In case you really need this in the context, you can implement this as:

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    
    # …
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update(
            texts=self.object.content
        )
        return context
```

In case you need *all* post objects, you can add these to the context:

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    
    # …
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update(
            texts=self.object.content,
            posts=Post.objects.all()
        )
        return context
```

and render these as:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {{ post.content }}
{% endfor %}
```

It might be better to work with an [**`F`** expression [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F) when incrementing the view counter to avoid *race conditions*:

class PostDetailView(DetailView):
model = Post
def get_object(self):
obj = super().get_object()
views = obj.view_count
obj.view_count = **F('view_count') + 1**
obj.save()
obj.view_count = **views+1**
return obj

Answer (score 1):

Just query all objects and loop the queryset to manipulate them according to your needs like so:

```
def your_view(self, **kwargs):

    # Get all table entries of Model Post
    queryset = Post.objects.all()

    # Loop each object in the queryset
    for object in queryset:

    # Do some logic
        print(object.content)

    [...]
    return (..., ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

first import models

```
from . models import Post
```

then in your function

```
data=Post.objects.values('content').all()
```

Now data have all the values in content field
data=[{'content':first_value},{'content':second_value},..like this...]

Comment: You will have hard times to map the new values to their objects again I guess